# Is there a way to search for a directory by name in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

So I remember the name of the directory I put a bunch of files in, but I don't remember what directory that directory is in. Is there a way to query directory names from a Google Drive Query?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Yes. If you need further help please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S: use *folder* instead of *directory*